# What's the difference between firebase default JSON security rules vs. Compilers like Bolt/Blaze

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

If Compilers export the same JSON security rules as default manually written JSON rules then why use Compilers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blaze and Bolt offer some conveniences that are more difficult to achieve in the JSON rules. For example, Bolt lets you define functions and types and re-use them throughout your rules; for JSON rules you have to copy and paste to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Aren't you the co-founder of firebase

Comment: Thank you very much... BTW where can I get Bolt/Blaze tutorials?